# Python: "'float' object has no attribute 'isin'" when comparing columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have data frame which looks like:

[image]

Now I am comparing whether two columns (i.e. complaint and compliment) have equal value or not: I have written a function:

```
def col_comp(x):
    return x['Complaint'].isin(x['Compliment'])
```

When I apply this function to dataframe i.e.

```
df.apply(col_comp,axis=1)
```

I get an error message

> AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'isin'", 'occurred
>   at index 0')

Any suggestion where I am making the mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isin` requires an iterable. You are providing individual data points (floats) with `apply` and `col_comp`. What you should use is `==` in your function `col_comp`, instead of `isin`. Even better, you can compare the columns in one call:

```
df['Complaint'] == df['Compliment']
```